# Atualizar todos os schemas com arquitetura multitenancy

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring, multi-tenancy

Bom dia.

Seguinte, tenho uma aplicação multitenancy utilizando Hibernate com JPA. Implantamos recentemente a arquitetura multitenancy e no persistence.xml estava configurado para atualizar automaticamente o schema default quando era feito deploy no projeto, isto foi retirado já que esta arquitetura não permite o uso desta propriedade. Porém agora não sei como atualizar todos os schemas que estão no banco de dados. Podem me apresentar soluções?

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Condigo pensar em várias opções para resolver este problema:

## 1. Use uma biblioteca de migrações

Esta é minha opção predileta, pois não consigo imaginar o Hibernate aplicando alterações automáticas em produção.

Você pode adotar uma biblioteca como [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) ou [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org/) para gerenciar scripts de alterações das diferentes versões do banco de dados. Essas bibliotecas cuidam ou pelo menos facilitam as atualizações de vários *schemas* ou bancos diferentes, basta configurá-las adequadamente.

Implementei há poucas semanas um projeto com o Flyway e foi muito fácil fazer a atualização de vários *schemas* no PostgreSQL. No caso, os *schemas* eram criados automaticamente e eu mantinha uma lista deles no `public` para então fazer a atualização.

Vou colocar um resumo da implementação que eu fiz usando o Spring Framework e o FlyWay. A classe a seguir utiliza duas instâncias do Flyway para gerenciar o schema `public` e os schemas específicos.

```
@Service
public class DatabaseMigration {

    @Autowired @Qualifier("public") Flyway publicFlyway;
    @Autowired @Qualifier("specific") Flyway specificFlyway;
    @Autowired SchemaService schemaService;

    @PostConstruct
    void migrate() {
        migratePublic();
        migrateAllSpecificSchemas();
    }

    /**
     * Updates public main schema when application is starting
     */
    void migratePublic() {
        publicFlyway.migrate();
    }

    /**
     * Updates all schemas when application is starting
     */
    void migrateAllSpecificSchemas() {
        List<String> schemas = schemaService.listAll();
        for (String schema : schemas) {
            specificFlyway.setSchemas(schema);
            specificFlyway.migrate();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Used when creating a new schema for a new client
     */
    public void migrateSpecificSchema(String schema) {
        specificFlyway.setSchemas(schema);
        specificFlyway.migrate();
    }

}
```

No meu projeto, que segue a estrutura do Maven, eu armazeno os scripts de migração do schema público e dos schemas específicos na seguinte estrutura de diretórios:

[image: Estrutura de diretórios]

E configura os beans do FlyWay da seguinte forma:

```
@Bean @Qualifier("public")
Flyway getFlywayPublicInstance(DataSource dataSource) {
    Flyway f = new Flyway();
    f.setDataSource(dataSource);
    f.setLocations(publicMigrationsDirectory);
    f.setOutOfOrder(true);
    return f;
}

@Bean @Qualifier("specific")
Flyway getFlywaySpecificInstance(DataSource dataSource) {
    Flyway f = new Flyway();
    f.setDataSource(dataSource);
    f.setLocations(specificMigrationsDirectory);
    f.setOutOfOrder(true);
    return f;
}
```

## 2. Inicialize o Hibernate em cada *Schema*

No início da aplicação, você pode inicializar manualmente o Hibernate uma vez para cada *schema*. Nunca fiz isso, mas deve funcionar bem.

Pesquisei um exemplo de como fazer isso e encontrei [este](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=987148):

```
Configuration config = new Configuration().configure();
config.setProperty("hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
SessionFactory sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();
sessionFactory = hibernateConfiguration.buildSessionFactory();
```

Após essa inicialização manual você pode descartar a sessão e usar a configuração multi-tenante normalmente.

## 3. Gere os scripts pelo Hibernate usando o `SchemaExport`

Com a classe [`SchemaExport`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.html) você pode gerar a DDL necessária e então aplicá-la nos diferentes *schemas*.

Há um [exemplo de exportação de DDL nesta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24239095/1683070). Basta fazer isso para cada *schema*.

## 4. Aplique as alterações pelo Hibernate usando o `SchemaExport`

Com a classe [`SchemaExport`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.html) você também pode forçar a atualização do banco via código.

Um exemplo, que pode estar um pouco defasado, está no final [desta página](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=987148):

```
AnnotationConfiguration config = new AnnotationConfiguration();
config.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
config.configure();
new SchemaExport(config).create(true, true);
```

Basta fazer isso para cada *schema*. No caso precisa se atentar para o método e os parâmetros usados no `SchemaExport`. Alguns comandos podem recriar ou apagar os elementos do banco de dados, outros podem gerar um arquivo com o script, outros somente atualizam o banco.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @utluiz, teria como me passar algum artigo que você já utilizou quanto o uso do Flyway ou Liquibase para realizar este tipo de operação?

Comment: A solução 2, 3 e 4 não vão sair deletando os dados? Fiz um teste aqui para gerar os scripts com o SchemaUpdate, ocorreu tudo certo, atualizou no banco quando o usuário informava o login e liberou um .sql, portanto achei melhor a 1° opção mesmo, por ter mais controle dos dados. @utluiz

Comment: @GiancarloGiulian As opções 2, 3 e 4 só vão deletar os dados se você usar a opção `drop-create` do Hibernate. Se usar a opção `update` não vai ter problema.

Comment: @GiancarloGiulian Atualizei a primeira parte da resposta com alguns exemplos de código. Espero que ajude.

Comment: muito obrigado, tinha setado a propriedade para dar update, porém estava deletando as tabelas e criando de novo utilizando a classe SchemaExport. E obrigado pelo complemento quanto ao Liquibase e Flyway que desconhecia. Ótimo trabalho para você (;