# Multi Tenancy com Hibernate update schema

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc, spring-jpa

Olá estou com uma aplicação que usa vários bancos de dados (multi-tenancy) usando hibernate. Gostaria de saber se alguém sabe alguma maneira de o Hibernate fazer o update no esquema dos bancos. Já setei a propriedade hibernate.hbm2dll.auto : update. mas não funciona.

Comment: Nunca encontrei, e procurei muito!! Sempre tive que criar os esquemas manualmente =/

Answer (score 1):

**Resposta:**

Você pode utilizar o framework `Flyway` para atualizar todos os schemas ou bancos de dados ao inicializar a sua aplicação.

**Referências:**

[Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/)

[Atualizar todos os schemas com arquitetura multitenancy](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50874/atualizar-todos-os-schemas-com-arquitetura-multitenancy)